# Wordpress custom dashboard button that changes stock status for products in the same category

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

Im creating a online delivery website (wordpress+woocommerce) for a friend that sells kebab.
The only thing is that at some point in the night, the kebab usually runs out and the store keeps selling other fast food items.

I would like to know if its possible to create a custom button in the admin dashboard so that it changes Stock status for all products in the same category or products that have the same tag. I know you can go to products and multiple edit the whole category but i want it to be as simple as possible since the staff may be in a hurry.

Any help appreciated. If you think there is a better & faster way to change the stock status feel free to advice me. Thanks.

Comment: you can maybe add stocks quantity and create a code that automatically resets it every morning...

Comment: Sadly, i cannot add quantities because there is a variety of products that include kebab and the quantity is not equal. Also, the staff may add a little bit more or less from time to time so you cannot calculate it exactly.